# Changing background based on data

Tags: c#, wpf, background, listbox

I have list of Computers which is source of some listBox [in C# WPF] and I want changing item background color based on some property like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace My_App
{
    public class Computer 
    {
       public int Status {get; private set; } = 1; // 0=bad 1=ok;
       //other stuff...
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<Computer> pcList = new ObservableCollection<Computer>();
            foreach(Computer c in pcList.Items)
            {
                if(c.Status == 1)
                {
                    pcListItem.Background == Color.Blue;
                }
                if(c.Status == 0)
                {
                    pcListItem.Background == Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote it rly simplyfied, but I need somethink like that `foreach` method. I found many examples but none was based on some data, everythink was general (for all items in list)...

Comment: What _specifically_ do you need help with? The usual way to do this is to put a trigger in the style for your item template or item container template, to set the background color based on the bound property value. Did you try that? Did you try _anything_?

Comment: Or, you can use a converter, as in the first duplicate I found. You can find additional information here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+listbox+item+background+